# How to call a child component method from parent in React Native typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

hello i'm new in React Native with typescript and in this example code i want to call testChild function from child Component in parentCall function in parent class and i dont know how to keep reference of each child component
i cant change child component code
how can i call testChild for each child component ?

```js
class parent extends React.Component {
   public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
         <child/>
         <child/>
               )
 public parentCall(): void{
   //call testChild for each Child component ??
}

}
class child extends React.Component {
 public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
               <Text>Text</Text>
               )

 public testChild (): string{
   return Data ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my problem with Using res and define childRef field 
and with this code i store ref of child component in childRef

`private  onRef= (ref) => this.childRef= ref`

and set it in child component

```
<child ref={this.onRef} />
```

now with childRef i can call its methods

```
childRef.testChild()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can store each `<Child />` component in an array like: `const children: JSX.Element[] = [Child, Child]`. The render method allows you to pass in arrays of components for rendering, so the added bonus of this is you now have a variable you can loop over and execute `testChild` with.